# why isn't 2nd IF statement read?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

The second `if` statement is not reached/read.

I switched order of the two `if` statements; only the first produces a result. I put semicolons various places, but now I understand they are optional. I removed the line space.

```js
function myChoices() {
 if (document.getElementById("state").checked) 
    {document.write("state")}
 else if (document.getElementById("county").checked) 
    {document.write("county")}
 else {document.write("country")}   

 if (document.getElementById("range30").checked) 
    {document.write("30yrs")}
 else if (document.getElementById("range50").checked) 
    {document.write("50 yrs")}
 else {document.write("100yrs")}   
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="region" id="state">State <br>
<input type="radio" name="region" id="county">county <br>
<input type="radio" name="region" id="country">country <br>
<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="timerange" id="range30">30 years<br>
<input type="radio" name="timerange" id="range50">50 years<br>
<input type="radio" name="timerange" id="range100">100 years<br>

<button onclick="myChoices()">my selections are made</button>
```

I select one choice from each set of radio buttons and click the button. Only the result from the first `if` is returned.

Why?

Comment: document.write might overwrite the document that contains the elements you‘re analyzing. Try console.log instead

Comment: I will learn what that is--thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `document.write`. As a rule of thumb, never use `document.write`.

In your example, when the first `if` statement calls `document.write`, it wipes out the HTML document and replaces it by e.g. `country`.

Then `if (document.getElementById("range30").checked)` runs, but `document.getElementById("range30")` doesn't find any element with id `range30` because the whole page has been wiped out and replaced by `country`, so it returns `null`. Trying to access `null.checked` throws an exception, which aborts execution of the function.

If you really want to use `document.write` (which I don't recommend), only call it once, at the end of your function:

```js
function myChoices() {
  var text = "";
  if (document.getElementById("state").checked) {
    text += "state";
  } else if (document.getElementById("county").checked) {
    text += "county";
  } else {
    text += "country";
  }

  if (document.getElementById("range30").checked) {
    text += "30yrs";
  } else if (document.getElementById("range50").checked) {
    text += "50 yrs";
  } else {
    text += "100yrs";
  }
  
  document.write(text);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="region" id="state">State <br>
<input type="radio" name="region" id="county">county <br>
<input type="radio" name="region" id="country">country <br>
<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="timerange" id="range30">30 years<br>
<input type="radio" name="timerange" id="range50">50 years<br>
<input type="radio" name="timerange" id="range100">100 years<br>

<button onclick="myChoices()">my selections are made</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand your answer because I don't know enough yet. This is a new way of thinking for me (last for me:Basic, Fortran, Pascal, etc lol)--that the code is part of the page and that a returned value can wipe out the code that created it. Can you suggest a command to use in place of "document.write" to get me started?

Comment: @Randall The code isn't getting wiped out; the document is. What do you mean by "a returned value"? What to use instead of `document.write` depends on what you're trying to do, which you haven't mentioned yet.

Comment: Ok! Yes that makes sense, although I want to know the result from both choices, so I could just combine two text variables--thanks a lot.

Comment: Melpomene, I'm trying to create a family ancestor timeline visual: I will be collecting  input from several radio button groups to determine which image to display. For example, if the user selects "county", timescale "30 years", the appropriate image, containing genealogical info on it, will be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above to responses, it is not a good idea to use document.write in callback as it will replace the document content when invoked after the document has loaded. If the document is still open then it will not replace the content.

It is always safer to use .appendChild() to add new DOM elements.

For your use case you can use .textContent to display the results.

```js
function myChoices() {
var resBox = document.getElementById("result");
var selectedRegion = "";
var selectedTimerange = "";

 if (document.getElementById("state").checked) 
    {selectedRegion ="state"}
 else if (document.getElementById("county").checked) 
    {selectedRegion = "county"}
 else {selectedRegion ="country"}   

 if (document.getElementById("range30").checked) 
    {selectedTimerange ="30yrs"}
 else if (document.getElementById("range50").checked) 
    {selectedTimerange ="50yrs" }
 else {selectedTimerange ="100yrs"}
 resBox.textContent = `${selectedRegion} ${selectedTimerange}`
 
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="region" id="state">State <br>
<input type="radio" name="region" id="county">county <br>
<input type="radio" name="region" id="country">country <br>
<br><br>
<input type="radio" name="timerange" id="range30">30 years<br>
<input type="radio" name="timerange" id="range50">50 years<br>
<input type="radio" name="timerange" id="range100">100 years<br>

<button onclick="myChoices()">my selections are made</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Since I want the result from BOTH radio groups, would I create var res1 and res2 and concatenate the two as output (not that I know how to do that yet, but surely that is straightforward)

Comment: @Randall, I have edited my answer to show result from both the selection.
I have used template literals. You can also do a simple string concatenation resBox.textContent = selectedRegion + " " + selectedTimerange

Comment: yes I understand that—thanks, although I don’t know what a template literal is,  will look it up! Actually I won’t be needing to print button choices, was just learning and testing how IF works in html. Eventually I will use current state of multiple radio groups to call up the appropriate background image , so as buttons are selected, the image changes. I’ll be back with many more questions—thank you and all

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the submit button, you will call the `myChoices()` function.

When it will first see a `document.write`, it will replace the whole HTML markup with your text in your `input`.

You can check the body of the result of your snippet:

[image]

Comment: I think I understand now, thanks. The radio buttons don't "exist" in the code, they exist on the page; then the document.write cleans the page slate and writes something immediately, without waiting to get to the end of the script. So @melpomene 's idea is to hold the selected states of the radio groups as variables until the end. Thanks again!